# Get Mtext data from dwg file

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, dwg, autocad-plugin

I have some interesting task. In one of drawings i've got a MText field. So, my plugin needs to know, how to get exactly that field from this drawing and others.
Is there any attributes or smth, what i can use for determining Mtext field on different drawings?

Comment: Maybe the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154613/ will help you along?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for...

```
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
    using AcApplication = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application;


    public static Document acDoc {
        get {
            return Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        }
    }

    public static MText getMTextObj(string TextYouNeed)
    {
        var ed = acDoc.Editor;
        var selMText = new TypedValue[1];
        selMText.SetValue(new TypedValue(0,"MTEXT"),0);
        var MTextObjs = ed.SelectAll(new SelectionFilter(selMText));

        using (var Transaction = acDoc.Database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()) {
            foreach (ObjectId MTextObjId in MTextObjs.Value.GetObjectIds()) {
                var current_MTextObj = Transaction.GetObject(MTextObjId,OpenMode.ForWrite) as MText;
                if(current_MTextObj.Text.Equals(TextYouNeed))
                    // return current_MTextObj;
                    // or
                    // do somehting else 
            }
        }
        Transaction.Commit(); // if you change something.
    }
```