# How we can read .dwg files using asp.net or c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want make simple applications how to read .dwg files in asp.net. What are procedure to read .dwg simple files in asp.net files. How we can read autocad files in asp.net or c#

Comment: Already a post about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298622/net-cad-component-that-can-read-write-dxf-dwg-files

Comment: The above link is down, alexandre

Answer (score 2):

DWG is proprietary file format, I think the way to go is vendor SDK, in this case AutoCAD SDK. See if .net is supported, or else you might need to unmanaged component in c++.

But have a look into this thread,

[.Net CAD component that can read/write dxf/ dwg files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298622/net-cad-component-that-can-read-write-dxf-dwg-files)

[Are there any libraries for parsing AutoCAD files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649181/are-there-any-libraries-for-parsing-autocad-files)

For Open source C++:

http://libdwg.sourceforge.net/en/

But above all depends on external components as i said before.

Comment: can we have simple application to view .dwg files in asp.net

Comment: As the other thread mentions, check out https://www.woutware.com/ , the library name is CADLib and has a free trial version of 30 days. The library should have api documentation and may be even some sample. You can give it a try.